How to create a bundled Js for renderer when doing `electron-forge start`
When running my Electron (Electron forge) app for local development, electron forge starts a local server and serves the renderer files via a local server.
Whereas when we make an EXE, it creates a bundled JS for respective renderers.
I would like to create bundled JS when doing local development as well.
I am using Vite + Typescript + Electron Forge, had used vite-typescript template from electronforge.
I have tried manually tweaking mode to production, command to build in vite.base.config.ts and vite.renderer.config.ts (no change for command here).
Only effect I was able to bring up was to not have a dev server running, but the bundling isn't still happening.
I can put up the configs if needed.
Any suggestions would really help!
